# Programatical navigation on NavigationView deeper than two views

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios-navigationview

Is there a way I can do programatical navigation with more than two views using NavigationView?

Like this: `View 1 -> View 2 -> View 3`

This is the sample code for what I'm trying to do:

```swift
class Coordinator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTag: String?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: Coordinator

    let things = ["first", "second", "third"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(things, id: \.self) { thing in
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(thing: thing),
                               tag: thing,
                               selection: self.$coordinator.selectedTag) {
                    Text(thing)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: Coordinator

    let thing: String
    let things = ["fourth", "fifth", "sixth"]

    var body: some View {
        List(things, id: \.self) { thing2 in
            NavigationLink(destination: ThirdView(thing: self.thing, thing2: thing2),
                           tag: thing2,
                           selection: self.$coordinator.selectedTag) {
                Text(thing2)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    let thing: String
    let thing2: String

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(thing) \(thing2)")
    }
}
```

I hoped that I could select a specific tag and deep navigate to the ThirdView but even the simple navigation won't work. If I select a link on the SecondView it will navigate forward and then back, instead of just navigating forward as expected.

I also tried using 2 variables, one to represent the tag of each screen but it also doesn't work.

Is there a way to make this work? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code is acting like there's another flow of navigation from `SecondView` to `ThirdView`, which I assume you're not intending to. If that's the intended case, you should also wrap `SecondView`'s body into a `NavigationView`, too.

Caveat: You'll have 2 navigation bars.

Without `tag` and `selection` (in `SecondView` or also in `ContentView`), your code works as intended. Is there a specific reason for using `tag` and `selection` here? I couldn't find a proper solution that both uses them and have only one `NavigationView`.